# Bug in my MIPS assembly code

Tags: assembly, mips

I have this code but is it not executing exactly how i want it to. 
It does the math correctly but prints out the wrong values at certain points.

For example if i enter 15 it should print out the following:

15
46
23
70
35
106
53
160
80
40
20
10
5
16
8
4
2
1

I expect this output because its been coded based of this

```
start : if (n == 1) stop ;
else if (n is even ) n = n/2;
else n = 3*n+1;
go to start ;
```

But it does

15
46
46
70
106
160
80
40
20
10
16
16
8
4
2

It also doesn't print out the 1 value, could someone please help? Also i suck at MIPS so please keep it to a basic level

Comment: _"if i enter 15 it should print out the following:  15 46 23 70 35 106 53 160 80 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1"_  You should explain _why_ you expect that output.

Comment: don't remove the code, it'll make people don't know what you've tried and what was the problem

Answer (score 1):

As stated in your last question, the problem is a bug in your original C program -- namely that you have n being divided by 2 after it is outputted.

To fix this move

```
# n = n / 2
srl $t0 $t0 1
```

Above:

```
# print n
move $a0 $t0
addi $v0 $zero 1
syscall
```

I can verify that this gives you the results that you are looking for.